# File Size in VB for Windows XP

Tags: file, vbscript, windows-xp, size

Hi this might sound weird, below is my VB Code

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set fileapp = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\TEST.txt", ForAppending, True) 
Set filewrt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\TEXT.txt", ForWriting, True) 
Set filesize = filesys.GetFile("C:\TEXT.txt")


filewrt.Write("HELOOO")
msgbox filesize.size
filewrt.close
```

This script shows the value '6' for 6bytes as the file size in Windows 7 but in XP it shows 0 even though the file size is 6 bytes .... any ideas ?

EDIT:

I figured it out, had to close the file first and then display the filesize.size for XP to display the proper file size.

Still don't know why this works on windows 7 ... any thoughts ?

Comment: this looks like VBScript, not VB.NET.  Please retag.

Comment: Corrections made ... so any thought as to why the size is retrieved in windows 7 before even closing 'filewrt' and not in XP?

Comment: @asawyer's answer seems feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be a change to file caching between the two versions of windows or the `FileSystemObject`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

> The Close method flushes the buffer and closes the file.

So the XP version isn't seeing the file size until the IO is flushed to the disk.